# Positioning and CSS Hover Fix

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm just trying to achieve the state to be the same by allowing the clickable hover link area to fill the whole block of each button region. The hover width is correct, but the bg image is over center of the link text. I want it to position just like in it's normal "up" state.

Here's the updated sample:

http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/test.html

```css
#aside_sect_mm {
  margin: 0px;
  background-position: 0%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  max-width: 704px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 140.8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like:

```
a:hover {
   margin-top: -50px;
   padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You helped point me in the right direction, I appreciate that. I further tweaked it off of your suggestion. I'm now trying to figure out with this new CSS setting for the hover state, what is causing the text to kick down so much? I was messing with the line height, but that seemed to shrink and scale the background image as well...?